# Shared memory parallel processing in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I have a list of strings and I want to bucket these list elements into appropriate buckets.

```
def bucketElements(i):
    global buckA, buckB, buckC
    if i.startswith('A'):
        buckA.add(i)
    elif i.startswith('B'):
        buckB.add(i)
    elif i.startswith('C'):
        buckC.add(i)
```

Now I want to call this method in parallel for each element inside my List. Something like this,

```
buckA,buckB, buckC = set(), set(), set()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=10)
pool.map(bucketElements, buckList)
```

Since I'm updating global variables inside my function I cannot use multiprocessing. is there anyway I can improve my processing? currently I'm calling it like this,

```
buckA,buckB, buckC = set(), set(), set()
for i in buckList:
    bucketElements(i)
```

Comment: what are the contents of `buckList`?

Comment: sorry my bad i mentioned as list of integers, it is actually list of strings

buckList = ['Adasdas', 'Asdsd', 'Xsadsad', 'Ssdsd', 'Bdasdsds']

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 Options:

- `Queue()`
- `Manager.Value()`
- `Manager.list()`

Python » Documentation: [multiprocessing.html#managers](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#managers)